# Woocommerce custom field returns a field in the ticket

Tags: woocommerce

I created a custom field (WooCommerce Checkout Manager) that appears in the checkout only if there is a specific product. Field and display works (wooccm11) with product ABC ID:90. Now I would like the ticket that is generated (fooevent plugin) after the payment to appear as an html/php field like for other functions, example:

`<?php if(!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsAttendeeCompany'])) :?><?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsAttendeeCompany']; ?><?php endif; ?>`

which adds the company name to the card.

If the ABC product is present and paid for, I would like to add an "ABC" word or even a ".png" image

If the product "ABC" but "NNN" is not present, nothing appears on the ticket. The ticket is a php file

Tnx

e.

I'd like to get some help solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the code, to add in the ticket (pdf) which is created and sent

```
<?php
 $order = wc_get_order($ticket["WooCommerceEventsOrderID"]);
    foreach ($order->get_coupon_codes() as $coupon_code) 
        $coupon_post_obj = get_page_by_title($coupon_code, OBJECT, 'shop_coupon');
        $coupon_id = $coupon_post_obj->ID;
        $coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon_id);
        if (in_array($coupon->get_code(), ["abc", "zot"])) 
            echo "<img src='http://abc.local/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/lunch-1.jpg' width='20px' height='20px' alt='' />”;
?>
```

I hope it can be of use to someone
e.